# How to create JWT for Google service account using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, jwt

According to this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth) i have successfully create JWT for Google service account using Java example and it's worked. However, these lines are still "magical" for me:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(resourceAsStream);
PrivateKey privateKey = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey();
```

But i can't repeat it using Node.js. Postman says "Could not get any response".

Here is my code.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const TOKEN_DURATION_IN_SECONDS = 3600;

const issueJWT = (
  issuedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
  serviceAccount = require('path/to/service-account.json')
) =>
  jwt.sign(
    {
      'iss': serviceAccount.client_email,
      'sub': serviceAccount.client_email,
      'aud': `https://${SERVICE_NAME}/${API_NAME}`,
      'iat': issuedAt,
      'exp': issuedAt + TOKEN_DURATION_IN_SECONDS,
    },
    serviceAccount.private_key,
    {
      algorithm: 'RS256',
      header: {
        'kid': serviceAccount.private_key_id,
        'typ': 'JWT',
        'alg': 'RS256',
      },
    }
  );
```

[Onlinde decoder](http://calebb.net/) show same header and body for tokens created using Node.js and Java.

So, i assume that signatures are different.

Via jwt from java:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer {jwt-from-java}" https://bigtableadmin.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{project-name}/instances -v
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 836
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 836 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 773
* schannel: decrypted data added: 773
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 773 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 34
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 34 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 5
* schannel: decrypted data added: 5
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 778 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 778 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 778
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Vary: X-Origin
< Vary: Referer
< Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2018 00:11:31 GMT
< Server: ESF
< Cache-Control: private
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
  "instances": [
    ...
  ]
}
* Connection #0 to host bigtableadmin.googleapis.com left intact
```

Via jwt from node.js:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer {jwt-from-node}" https://bigtableadmin.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{project-name}/instances -v
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 836
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 836 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 773
* schannel: decrypted data added: 773
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 773 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 34
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 34 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 5
* schannel: decrypted data added: 5
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 778 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 778 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 778
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
< Vary: X-Origin
< Vary: Referer
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2018 00:08:58 GMT
< Server: ESF
< Cache-Control: private
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See     https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
* Connection #0 to host bigtableadmin.googleapis.com left intact
```

How can i create JWT for Google service account using Node.js?

Comment: Can you provide the full details of the error (perhaps, a screenshot of the error)? “Could not get any response" is very generic.

Comment: @oakinlaja Added curl output

Answer (score 0):

So from the error message it looks like this is not a JWT specific issue. This Google Groups [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-dev/ZRYU2CKa6kg) shows that the issue is due an incorrect CURL command being used. Check the curl command syntax and access token placement to make sure it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, now it's works without any changes in code.